# C++ Printing floats with specified number of decimal places

Tags: c++, floating-point, numbers

I have numbers stored in a `float` and I want it to print up to 5 decimal places. The only problem is that I don't want to print 0s afterwards, nor actually modifying the number.

For example:

- 1 should be printed as 1 **(not 1.00000)**
- 0.5 should be printed as 0.5 **(not 0.50000)**
- 0.333333333 should be printed as 0.33333

I know `setprecision` does set the number of significant digits, but when I set it to `fixed`, it prints out the 0s also. Is there a way around this?

For example, if the number is 1.33333 (with exactly 5 decimal places), `setprecision(5)`, prints out 1.3333, which is what I **don't** want.

Any tips would be appreciated!

**EDIT**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iomanip>
int main()
{
  float a = 1;
  float b = 0.5;
  float c = 0.3333333333333;
  float d = 1.33333;

  std::cout << std::setprecision(5);
  std::cout << a << "\n";
  std::cout << b << "\n";
  std::cout << c << "\n";
  std::cout << d << "\n"; // returns 1.3333
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: yes but if the number is say 1.33333 exactly, it prints out 1.3333

Comment: Can you show an example with some code?  Dropping `std::fixed` should remove any trailing 0's

Comment: added in code in my edit above

Comment: Cool.  I removed my dupe comment as this is a different issue.  I don't think there is anything you can use that is baked into `cout`.  I believe you'll have to use a `std::stringstream` and trim off the trailing 0's to get this behavior.

Comment: Can you use boost::format?  I rolled my own type-safe (variadic template) function to do this kind of stuff. `dj::oprintf("%7.5g %7.5g\n", 1.0/3, 0.5);` That does what you want, and by default writes to std::cout. (I thoroughly dislike iostream chaining of `operator<<`. Have since the inception.)